# Computing the expected value of a new Normal Random Variable (transformation)

Tags: normal-distribution, random-variable, expected-value

I have the following exercise to do:

Let X be a normally distributed variable with mean μ and variance σ^2, i.e. X∼N(μ,σ^2). Define a new random variable to be Z=X^2−X. Compute the Expected Value of Z

I was thinking I could just do E(Z)=E(X^2)-E(X) and end up with σ^2 - μ, but this feels "too easy".. Any help is super appreciated!

Comment: Note that $E[X^2] \neq \sigma^2 = E[(X-\mu)^2]$, but you are on the right track…

Comment: The answer is not important, its me showing how I get there. So, the answer will be (^2+^2) -  ? If this Is the case I understand, if not I feel lost...

Comment: Linearity of expectation would seem to be an obvious thing to use, just as you suggest. There's various ways to go about it  but the direct approach is simple enough here.